# Void Function Equivalent in scala?

Tags: scala, foreach, void, scalatest

```
val list = List(4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14)
list.foreach(num ⇒ println(num * 4))
list should be()
```

I have tried to figure what it should be but don't quite get the answer. I think that it has to be empty or like a void function in Java but I do not know the equivalent in Scala.
[image]

Comment: scala has `Unit` which is equivalent to Void in java. Eg. `def doSomething: Unit = println("foo")`. Your question not clear, what you are trying to do. you list would still be `List(4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14)` in you example. Do you think `foreach` eats elements on iteration? it does not.

Comment: Doesn't the text in the screenshot give the answer to your question? It says that a return type of `Unit` in Scala is an equivalent to a `void` return type in Java.

Comment: What are those parenthesis around Int? It should be List.empty[Int] and not List.empty(Int)

Comment: `list` should **not** be `void` or `empty`. It is populated with 7 elements and is unchanged. `foreach()` returns `Unit` but you are not capturing the return value so you can't test for it.

Answer (score 2):

void equivalent in Scala would be `Unit`, `foreach` does return Unit.

```
def foreach(f: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

So the proper (and useless) test will be this:

```
list should be(List(4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14))
```

Also take into consideration that even it the function returns something, you are not capturing it so the list will remain unchanged.

If you want to retrieve the result of a function you should assign it to another value, something like this below: (Using `map` to show this):

```
val result = list.map(num ⇒ num * 4)
result should be(List(16, 24, 28, 32, 36, 52, 56))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by void function, but there is a way to represent empty list like this:

```
list should be List.empty[Int]
```

Answer (score 0):

void in java means there is no return value, Unit in scala serves the same purpose.

When you do list.foreach then there is no return value and list is not changed (or rather the return value is Unit), instead the function is applied to each member and the return value is discarded.

I imagine you are instead looking to do a flatmap. list.flatmap(f) would apply f on each element and assume the value return from f is a collection and then flatten it. for example if list is (0, 2, 4) and f returns a list with 1 repeated the member value then f would return list(), list(1,1) and list(1, 1, 1, 1) then the returned value would be list(1,1,1,1,1,1)

In this case, just return list() to have a total return value of list().